# Adding category rows based on matching item properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a sorted, static list to display with KO, and wanted to show category headers whenever the category changed (since the list is sorted by category). I'm still genning up on KO, is this the "KO" way to do this, or is there a better approach? In particular the syntax to access the previous item in the list is a bit hairy, which makes me suspect I'm missing a feature that would improve this. :-)

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ULUzogIw/1/) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ULUzogIw/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 || $parent.items()[$index() - 1].category() !== category() -->
    <tr class="category">
      <td colspan="2" data-bind="text: category"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
      <td class="num" data-bind="text: quantity"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript: *(Obviously this is just a quick and dirty VM for the example)*

```
function Item(category, item, quantity) {
    this.category = ko.observable(category);
    this.item = ko.observable(item);
    this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
}

var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("Fruit", "Apples", 27),
        new Item("Fruit", "Oranges", 17),
        new Item("Fruit", "Kiwis", 3),
        new Item("Vegetables", "Celery", 16),
        new Item("Vegetables", "Carrots", 72),
        new Item("Sundries", "Toothpaste", 10),
        new Item("Sundries", "Washing-up liquid", 8)
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

Result: *(there's some trivial CSS that isn't relevant)*

[image: Table with category rows]

Comment: What should happen if you mix the categories? Eg. "Vegetables Fruit Vegtable Fruit" is the order. Will you need two Vegrable and Fruit labels or only one? http://jsbin.com/ULUzogIw/2/edit

Comment: @nemesv: *"...since the list is sorted by category..."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you modify your observable array and construct it to contain an array of items with associated quantities you can do the following:

**JS:**

```
function Item(category, itemList) {
    this.category = ko.observable(category);
    this.itemList = ko.observableArray(itemList);

}

var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("Fruit", [{"item": "Apples", "qty": 27 }, 
                           {"item": "Oranges", "qty": 17}, 
                           {"item": "Kiwis", "qty": 3}]),              
        new Item("Vegetables", [{"item": "Celery", "qty": 16},
                                {"item": "Carrots", "qty": 72}]),      
        new Item("Sundries", [{"item": "Toothpaste", "qty": 10},
                              {"item": "Washing-up liquid", "qty": 8}]),    
    ])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">    
    <tr class="category">
      <td colspan="2" data-bind="text: category"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: itemList -->
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
          <td class="num" data-bind="text: qty"></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4yPv/2/

Comment: I'm not keen on reformatting the list to that degree, but this definitely makes for a cleaner approach.

Comment: This does stop you having to detect the changes in category using the logic you have within your foreach. I assume your actual list is much more complex than the sample data you submitted, hence you are not keen to reformat?

Comment: Yeah, this.  Anytime you're doing things like `$parent.items()[$index() - 1]` it's almost certainly time to step back and re-evaluate.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, hence the question. :-) `$parent.items()[$index() - 1]` just said "hack" to me.

Comment: @T.J. - nah, not a hack.  Think of your ViewModel as a live, magically always in-sync representation of your view.  If you try to structure your VM one way, and your view another, you're in for trouble :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: No no, I meant `$parent.items()[$index() - 1]` just said "hack" to me. (I've edited the comment now, so it can't be read the other way.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder bite the bullet... reformat your list, you know it makes sense :-)

Comment: @Tanner: Definitely feels like the cleanest approach. (And although I didn't want to, I *already* have to preprocess it for other reasons, so...)

Comment: Nice job Tanner, you helped the #31 top Stack Overflow user, and the #2 top JavaScript user *of all time* :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a categoryId to the item, and sort by them. It gives you possibility to separate items for simple items and categories:

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <!-- ko if: type == 0 -->
        <tr class="category">
            <td colspan="2" data-bind="text: item"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: type == 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
            <td class="num" data-bind="text: quantity"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

viewModel:

```
function Item(type, categoryId, item, quantity) {
    this.type = type;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.item = ko.observable(item);
    this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
}

var vm = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item(0, 1, "Fruit"), 
        new Item(1, 1, "Apples", 27),
        new Item(1, 1, "Oranges", 17),
        new Item(1, 1, "Kiwis", 3),
        new Item(0, 2, "Vegetables"),
        new Item(1, 2, "Celery", 16),
        new Item(1, 2, "Carrots", 72),
        new Item(0, 3, "Sundries"),
        new Item(1, 3, "Toothpaste", 10),
        new Item(1, 4, "Washing-up liquid", 8)
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

Comment: That requires pre-processing the list in what seems to me to be a non-KO way

Comment: No, it can be done in your viewModel. You can get original data from server, and then add categoryId. Your viewModel tells how data should be dsiplayed, so you can modify this data as you want.

Comment: @ Alexander: Adding the category ID *is* the preprocessing I was talking about. Thanks for the suggestion, but what I already have seems more straightforward and less error-prone to me. (In any case, the answer is useful, even if I think it's not the way to go.)